# Get the equivalent index value in a 2 arrays using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to assigned a value on Column B depending on the condition in Column A. I formulate a simple code using IF...ElseIf condition (see **code** below). I have 1000 conditions and I am thinking if I can use a 2 separate arrays for the value of Column A and get the index of the value in column A to 1st array (Array1 ) and match it to the 2nd array (AssignedArray). Something like, for each value found in Column A check the Array1 if the value is exist and get the index and match the index to AssignedArray. Like for example,

```
Array1 = Array("DL2005", "EFRUEN", "DESTDIDIER", "EOGRADY3", "EKARLSON1", "EOKUTOMI1")
AssignedArray = Array("Trader", "Trader", "Operations", "Trader", "Analyst", "Operations")
```

**CODE**

```
For x = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each wrd In Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1)
        val = wrd

        If UCase(val) = "DL2005" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value = "Trader"
        ElseIf UCase(val) = "EFRUEN" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value = "Trader"
        ElseIf UCase(val) = "DESTDIDIER" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value = "Operations"
        ElseIf UCase(val) = "EOGRADY3" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value = "Trader"
        ElseIf UCase(val) = "EKARLSON1" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value = "Analyst"
        ElseIf UCase(val) = "EOKUTOMI1" Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value = "Operations"
        End If
    Next wrd
Next x
```

Is it possible to do that?Or is there any way on how to simplify my code instead of using IF ELSEIF condition.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, using MATCH for example.

Comment: try not to use keywords like `val` as variables.  You could use a sheet also with the corresponding values in and just get the result of a vlookup or code using match and offset in the same way.  i.e. DL2005 in A Trader in B etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1k conditions (as you do), then I imagine neither `If` nor `Select` statements are appropriate. Furthermore, creating/maintaining expressions (in your code) that evaluate to two 1k-element arrays may be burdensome.

A maintenance friendly approach might be to keep the items in `Array1` on some worksheet, and keep the contents of `AssignedArray` right next to it. Something like the below. Say the yellow values are items that you would have put into `Array1` and green values are items you would have put into `AssignedArray` (I only have 25 as an example).

[image: Dummy data]

Then you wouldn't necessarily need any VBA and could purely use Excel functions like `VLOOKUP` -- or `MATCH` and `INDEX` in conjunction. For example, I put this formula in cell `E4`, which tries to find the value in `D4` among the values in column A and returns the corresponding value from column B:

`=INDEX($B$1:$B$25,MATCH(D4,$A$1:$A$25,0))`

[image: Formula approach]

If you still wanted to use VBA, this code should loop over cells `D4:D8` (which is the correct range for my spreadsheet, but probably not for yours), make them uppercase (in memory only, not on the sheet), then write the corresponding values in `G4:G8`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FillInAssociatedValuesValue()
    Dim inputKeys() As Variant ' <-- AKA Array1
    inputKeys = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A25").Value2 ' Change to wherever items from Array1 are kept

    Dim inputValues() As Variant '<-- AKA AssignedArray
    inputValues = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B25").Value2 ' Change to wherever items from AssignedArray are kept

    If (UBound(inputKeys, 1) - LBound(inputKeys, 1)) <> (UBound(inputValues, 1) - LBound(inputValues, 1)) Then
        MsgBox ("The number of keys should be the same as the number of associated values. Code will stop running now.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim dict As Object 'Shouldn't need to add a reference
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 

    ' One pass to fill the dictionary. If there are duplicates, will only add first instance.
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = LBound(inputKeys, 1) To UBound(inputKeys, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(inputKeys(rowIndex, 1)) Then
            dict.Add UCase$(inputKeys(rowIndex, 1)), inputValues(rowIndex, 1)
        End If
    Next rowIndex

    Dim Key As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rowIndex = 4 To 8 ' I needed to loop over range D4:D8
            Key = UCase$(.Cells(rowIndex, "D").Value2)

            If dict.Exists(Key) Then
                .Cells(rowIndex, "G").Value2 = dict.Item(Key)
            Else
                ' Some logic in case input is not found, and cannot be mapped to some associated value
                .Cells(rowIndex, "G").Value2 = "VALUE NOT FOUND"
            End If
        Next rowIndex
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple; use `For` loops to compare `Array1` to each cell in `column A` and if there is a match, use `Offset` put the corresponding element from `AssignedArray` into the cell on the right.

```
Dim Array1 As Variant, AssignedArray As Variant
Dim x As Long, i As Long

Array1 = Array("DL2005", "EFRUEN", "DESTDIDIER", "EOGRADY3", "EKARLSON1", "EOKUTOMI1")
AssignedArray = Array("Trader", "Trader", "Operations", "Trader", "Analyst", "Operations")

For x = 2 To Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
        If Cells(x, 1).Value = Array1(i) Then
            Cells(x, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = AssignedArray(i)
        End If
    Next i
Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Array1, AssignedArray
    Dim s As String, i As Integer, r As Long, x As Long
    Dim k As Integer

    Array1 = Array("DL2005", "EFRUEN", "DESTDIDIER", "EOGRADY3", "EKARLSON1", "EOKUTOMI1")
    AssignedArray = Array("Trader", "Trader", "Operations", "Trader", "Analyst", "Operations")

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    r = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With Ws
        For x = 1 To r
            s = UCase(.Cells(x, 1))
            For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
                If s = Array1(i) Then
                    k = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            .Cells(x, 3) = AssignedArray(k)
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

If you have a lot of data, it is better to speed up the results by arranging the results into a single sheet instead of entering them one by one into the cell.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Array1, AssignedArray
    Dim s As String, i As Integer, r As Long, x As Long
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim vDB, vR()

    Array1 = Array("DL2005", "EFRUEN", "DESTDIDIER", "EOGRADY3", "EKARLSON1", "EOKUTOMI1")
    AssignedArray = Array("Trader", "Trader", "Operations", "Trader", "Analyst", "Operations")

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)

    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        r = UBound(vDB, 1)
        ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 1)
        For x = 1 To r
            s = UCase(vDB(x, 1))
            For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
                If s = Array1(i) Then
                    k = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            vR(x, 1) = AssignedArray(k)
        Next x
        .Range("c1").Resize(r) = vR
    End With

End Sub
```